# Model builder generating empty output

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, model

In the model below, I get an empty output if I run it from start to finish. It works though if I first individually run the project and create fishnet tools, then run the entire model. Something is happening around the create fish net tool and I can't figure out what. I've included the tool dialog box after it's been run.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting Create Fishnet as a Precondition to Clip (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/setting-precondition.htm)

Comment: That didn't seem to work. If the precondition was set correctly, I would have had a solid and dashed line connecting Full_Grid to Clip?

Comment: Yes. Are Block_Projected_UTM and Full_grid in the same coordinate system?

Comment: When I run the project and create fishnet individually and then run entire model after, the fishnet (Full_Grid) comes out in the same coordinate system.

Comment: And if you run the complete model? You might have some Environment setting that change coordinate system: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm#GUID-05CABB29-0758-4742-954C-7844DEC6D113